# How do I test the convergence of this series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n cos^2(n!)}{n 3^n}$

I tried some tests, but they were inconclusive. Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\cos^2(n!)\le1$, so

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^n\cos^2(n!)}{n3^n}\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2/3)^n}n$$

Note that $\frac{(2/3)^n}n\le(2/3)^n$:

$$\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty(2/3)^n$$

This geometric series converges since $|2/3|\le1$.

Comment: We could add that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2/3)^n}n=\log(3)$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici True, but the upper bound with the geometric series is more simplistic.

Comment: For sure, I totally agree with you ! Cheers :-)